# Do you know more experts?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Have you noticed the invitation box on the right hand panel of our main site?

[image: Picture of invitation box]

This allows you to invite any computer graphics experts you may know who may be interested in joining the private beta. We don't need to wait until public beta to invite them - they can join in now.

If you don't have anyone in mind who you know, do you have any suggestions of specific areas of expertise that we need to see represented here? That might give someone else a prompt to think of someone they hadn't yet considered inviting...

Comment: I know two people who can act as experts for this website,They are namely:Dr.S.Upadhyay,The would-be-VC of Banaras Hindu University and his wife,who is the would-be-head of the Eklavya Books Committee http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/90/do-you-know-more-experts?cb=1